# Cache ? what you suggest to use

Tags: php, caching

After finishing, the website structure, and php coding, now i want to launch it online.
But  it will be under a heavy traffic about 400 visitors every second, when it will be launched online, and i wanted some expert opinions, about the cache.

- What kind of cache i should use ? APC or eAccelerator ?
- I have already installed memcached, will this be in conflict with APC or eAccelerator ?
- Where can i read about how to configure the caches ? any suggestion about an optimal configuration ?
- What about to cache only some pages and not all the website, is this possible, if yes, please can give any kind of example ?

Thank you for reading this message 
Best Regards
Meo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC and memcache can be used together. 400 visitors per second is quite a lot. Maybe you should investigate the possibilities of a load balancer and a server setup with 2 or 3 webservers. That way, you can spread the load and will even be able to stay online when one of the servers fails.

I don't know what this website is about and if it relies on databases too, but sites with lots of data, with searches and filtes (think about shops, wiki's etc) will need a heavy (and separate) database server too. In these situations, the database is more likely to be the bottleneck than the webserver itself.

If you have much static content, you can cache much of the data, or even complete or partially rendered pages or chunks of HTML in memcache. That may seriously reduce database load.

Comment: what about to cache only some specific files. like single.php file, example : wwww.mywebsite.com/single.php?id=5451545  , so i want cache all files that are generated from single.php not from other files.. is this possible ? thank you